# Почему foreach из всего массива берет только первую строку?

Tags: php, laravel

По началу таблица пуста:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем заполняю ее информацией

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И Вот этот код срабатывает только на первую запись, то есть код не должен создавать еще одну запись с таким же id_match. Цикл foreach не перебирает все записи, а только первую, почему? И как сделать чтоб цикл перебирал все записи из таблицы? Может проблема в запросе?

```
public function BetsOne(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();
    $bets = Bet::all()->where('user',Auth::id());

    if($bets->isEmpty()){
        $info = InfoUser::where('user_id',Auth::id())->first()->balans;
        if($request->summa <= $info){
            $bet = new Bet();
            $bet->fill($input);
            $bet->save(); //записыаем все с формы в табилцу bets

            $iu = InfoUser::where('user_id',Auth::id())
                ->decrement('balans', $request->summa);

            $match = Match::find($request->id_match);
            $match->balans_one = $match->balans_one + $request->summa; //перезаписываем поле balans_one
            $proc = ceil($match->balans_one * 100 / ($match->balans_one+$match->balans_two));
            $koff = round(100/$proc, 2);//коэффициент
            $match->koof_one = $koff;
            if($match->balans_two != 0){
                $proc_two = 101 - $proc;
                $koff_two = round(100/$proc_two,2);
                $match->koof_two = $koff_two;
            }
            if($match->save()){
                Session::flash('store', 'Ваша ставка принята!');
                return redirect()->route('home');
            }
        }else{
            Session::flash('danger','Недостаточно средств на вашем счету!');
            return redirect()->route('home');
        }
    }else{
        foreach($bets as $b){
            if($b->id_match != $request->id_match){
                $info = InfoUser::where('user_id',Auth::id())->first()->balans;
                if($request->summa <= $info){
                    $bet = new Bet();
                    $bet->fill($input);
                    $bet->save(); //записыаем все с формы в табилцу bets

                    $iu = InfoUser::where('user_id',Auth::id())
                        ->decrement('balans', $request->summa);

                    $match = Match::find($request->id_match);
                    $match->balans_one = $match->balans_one + $request->summa; //перезаписываем поле balans_one
                    $proc = ceil($match->balans_one * 100 / ($match->balans_one+$match->balans_two));
                    $koff = round(100/$proc, 2);//коэффициент
                    $match->koof_one = $koff;
                    if($match->balans_two != 0){
                        $proc_two = 101 - $proc;
                        $koff_two = round(100/$proc_two,2);
                        $match->koof_two = $koff_two;
                    }
                    if($match->save()){
                        Session::flash('store', 'Ваша ставка принята!');
                        return redirect()->route('home');
                    }
                }else{
                    Session::flash('danger','Недостаточно средств на вашем счету!');
                    return redirect()->route('home');
                }
            }else{
                Session::flash('danger','Вы уже сделали ставку на этот матч');
                return redirect()->route('home');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Может проблема в строке `if($b->id_match != $request->id_match)`? Там у вас значение 1 и поэтому только 1 раз отрабатывает код

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan нет не потому, просто в  `else` стоит `return` и функция прекращает свою работу.

Comment: @Digital Core Кстати.. да, возможно

Comment: @Digital Core А в каком else? Можете уточнить? И на что заменить return?

Comment: @DigitalCore да, верно, не заметил это.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы должны построить функцию таким образом, чтоб завершение работы функции `return` вызывалось только после выполнения всех задач.

```
function Function_Name ($arg) {
    foreach(var t in $arg){
        if(t)
            return; // выход из цикла, и функции с значением NULL
    }
    var $result = ...
    return $result; // завершение работы функции - возврат результата
    }
```

Этот код завершится при первом вхождении `true` в `arg` - если вам нужно обработать весь массив аргументов, не вызывайте в цикле `return`